# How to access distinct elements of a tuple inside an array, passed as function argument?

Tags: python, arrays, function, tuples

I am trying to manipulate distinct elementf of a tuple, which is part of an array.

What I have:

```py
def my_function(lis):
  for i in lis:
    x[i], y[i], z[i] = lis[i]
  ...
```

As in the main I have:

```py
my_function([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,11,12)]):
  ...
```

The result was:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

As mentioned, I am trying to access distinc element of the tuple from the function and manipulate them.

Comment: this line `x[i], y[i], z[i] = lis[i]` should be `x, y, z = i`

Answer (score 4):

Each `i` *is* a tuple; you probably want

```
for i in lis:
    x, y, z = i
    # use x, y, and z
```

or simply

```
for x, y, z in lis:
    # use x, y, and z
```

Comment: Mybe it would be too obvious to ask, but as I am trying to implement this, I am not sure, how to use the intermidiate steps. Therefore, I was thinking to store the data in an array, such as:
```python
x = y = z = [0] * len(lis)
for i in lis:
    ind = 0
    x[ind], y[ind], z[ind] = i
    ind += 1
```
Is this the more convenient way to use it